# c++ exp function different results under x64 on i7-3770 and i7-4790

Tags: c++, 64-bit, precision, exp

When I execute a simple x64 application with the following code, I get different results on Windows PCs with a i7-3770 and i7-4790 CPU.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void main()
{
  double val = exp(-10.240990982718174);
  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
  std::cout << val;
}
```

Result on i7-3770:

```
3.5677476354876406e-05
```

Result on i7-4790:

```
3.5677476354876413e-05
```

When I modify the code to call

```
unsigned int control_word;
_controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_UP, MCW_RC);
```

before the exp function call, both CPUs deliver the same results.

My questions:

- Does anyone have an idea for the reason of the differences between the i7-3770 and i7-4790?
- Is there a way to set the floating point precision or consistency in a Visual Studio 2015/2017 C++ project for the whole project and not only for the following function call? The "Floating Point Model" setting (/fp) does not have any influence on the results here.

Comment: According to http://www.ttmath.org/online_calculator the first 20 or so digits should be 0.000035677476354876 393107 (I've added a space to show where the digits start to diverge). The first result is slightly closer.

Comment: Not relevant to the question but `main` returns int, not void

Comment: There is almost certainly an Evil DLL getting injected into your process that changes the control word.  Do note that `_RC_UP` is *not* the default, it is `_RC_NEAR`.  So whatever machine you consider the "good" one is actually the troublemaker.  Hunting for that DLL can keep you busy for a while.  It is the kind of problem that a disk format tends to solve a lot quicker, especially when it isn't you that has to do it.

Comment: I am aware that this is not the default behavior. But this is the only possiblity  I currently found which gives me the same results on both CPU types. Furthermore I tried this on more PCs with different CPUs and I have got the impression that all PCs with Ivy Bridge and prior CPUs deliver the same results (3.5677476354876406e-05) and all Haswell and later CPUs deliver also the same results (3.5677476354876413e-05). Could it be possible, that beginning with Haswell rounding of double precision values under x64 has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math precision requirements of C and C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945815/math-precision-requirements-of-c-and-c-standard)

Comment: complex functions like sin, cos, exp are not required to be properly rounded by IEEE-754. Those values differ by only 1ULP which is normal. See [`sin(45)` and `cos(45)` giving different results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31509019/995714)

Comment: and [`void main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714) is prohibited in C++ and C although it's allowed in free-standing C implementations

Comment: another possible duplicate: [`exp` precision between Mac OS and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15216884/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further investigations and I found out the following facts:

- the problem does also occur on Windows with a different compiler (Intel)
- on a linux system both values are equal

I also posted this question to the Visual Studio Community. I got the information, that Haswell and newer CPUs use FMA3. You can disable this feature with **_set_FMA3_enable(0)** at the beginning of the program. When I do this, the results are the same.

Comment: This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-fma3-enable-set-fma3-enable?view=vs-2017 "By default, on X64 platforms, the CRT startup code detects whether the CPU supports FMA3 instructions, and enables or disables the FMA3 implementations in the library."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that double is coded using IEEE-754, and using this [decimal to binary converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html), you can see that:

> 3.5677476354876406e-05 is represented in hexa as 0x3F02B48CC0D0ABA8
>   3.5677476354876413e-05 is represented in hexa as 0x3F02B48CC0D0ABA9

which differ only in the last bit, probably due round error.